# ffmpeg - pipe video output as a normal file

Tags: ffmpeg, format, pipe, codec

I want to be able to write ffmpeg video output to stdout as if it was a normal file. I want the video to be able to be seekable (streamable videos can't), but I don't want to save it to disk immediately.

If I use 
`cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -r 30 -i - -f mov - > 1.mp4` 
It errors because the mov format isn't streamable
`muxer does not support non seekable output`

Is there some way to force ffmpeg to pipe it as if it was a normal file?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with MP4/MOV. ffmpeg generates the indices for streams in memory and writes them to file when all streams are EOF.

Works for me with MKV. Should work with MPEG-TS as well.

Comment: I want to make videos that are playable in html5 (and on as many devices as possible). I found this discussion: https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/346#issuecomment-67299526
And I was able to do what I wanted with `-movflags empty_moov`. It sounds like that would make it not seekable (I might end up being fine with that), but it still seemed to seek fine. I'm not sure exactly what the moov is; are there any problems I might have with compatibility if I use this?